# Got an error when run a powershell script inside a powershell script in Azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-powershell

I have a pipeline task which is as follow:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
displayName: 'Script1'      
inputs:
  filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/helloworld1.ps1'
```

And it run a helloworld1.ps1 , but the helloworld1.ps1 script call another script.
here's the code of helloworld1:

```
Write-Host 'Hello from 1st File.'

. ./helloworld2.ps1
```

And the helloworld2.ps1 scripts contains this one line only:

```
Write-Host 'Hello from 2nd File.'
```

BUT, when when pipelines triggers, its run the script1 and print its first line and then failed on 2nd line throwing the error:

```
 | The term './helloworld2.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a
 | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check
 | the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
 | that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Is the path correct for `helloworld2.ps1` ? Where is the script located? Try also `powershell.exe .\helloworld2.ps1`

Comment: Does it work if you change `./helloworld2.ps1` to `$PSScriptRoot/helloworld2.ps1` ?

Comment: @GeralexGR the path is correct because when i run the script locally on powershell it worked perfetly. also the helloworld2.ps1 is in the same directory.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, I've just tried it... it throw this error
   
     |  $PSScriptRoot/helloworld2.ps1
     |                ~
     | You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator

Comment: @YanSklyarenko  kindly have a look at this one too... Now I'm facing error on calling functions. from another script.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446559/error-while-calling-function-in-powershell-through-azure-devops-pipelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer of my own question. After using PSScriptRoot, the issue is resolved! so the correct helloworld1.ps1 is as follow:

```
 Write-Host 'Hello from 1st File.'

 & "$PSScriptRoot/helloworld2.ps1"
```