# Error while calling function in powershell through azure-devops Pipelines

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a pipeline task which is as follow:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
displayName: 'Script1'      
inputs:
  filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/helloworld1.ps1'
```

And it run a helloworld1.ps1 , but the helloworld1.ps1 script call another script.
here's the code of helloworld1:

```
 & "$PSScriptRoot/helloworld2.ps1"
 Write-Host 'Hello from 1st File.'
 printHello
```

And the helloworld2.ps1 scripts contains this one line only:

```
function printHello()
{
Write-Host 'Hello from 2nd File.'
}
```

BUT, when when pipelines triggers, its run the Helloworld1.ps1 and print its 2nd line and then failed on 3rd line throwing the error:

```
 | The term 'PrintHello' is not recognized as a name of a
 | cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check
 | the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
 | that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: The Call Operator (e.g. ```& .\somescript.ps1```) runs a script in a *child* scope which means that any variables and functions defined inside the script are only available inside that script. If you want functions to still be available *after* the child script has finished you can use the Dot Sourcing Operator (e.g. ```. .\somescript.ps1```) instead - see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators

Comment: @mclayton you should post that as an Answer. I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document will tell you how to do it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/10-script-modules?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-functions

And below scripts works on my side:

My structure:

[image]

YAML file:

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './p_main.ps1'
```

main PowerShell script file:

```
# This is p_main.ps1
. $env:System_DefaultWorkingDirectory\p_sub.ps1
Get-ChildItem -Path Function:\printHello
Write-Host 'Hello from 1st File.'
printHello
```

How to **Use predefined variables**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken

Another PowerShell script file:

```
# This is p_sub.ps1
function printHello()
{
Write-Host 'Hello from 2nd File.'
}
```

Works well:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `$MyInvocation` variable to get the current path of the script running.  The `MyCommand.Path` returns the full path of the script running (C:\path\helloworld1.ps1). Use `Split-Path` to remove the filename and just get the path.

Add the following to the helloworld1.ps1 file:

```
$cd = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
. "$cd\helloworld2.ps1"
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you aren't dependent of AzDO environment variables.  The script works no matter if you run it from a AzDO pipeline, or your local dev PS terminal.